# xen won't start

Tags: ubuntu, xen

Server IBM x3650 M3

Xeon E5506, 50G RAM, Ubuntu 12.10

*grub.cnf*

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.1-amd64 and Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d07e5080-84ec-4de0-b51b-55af777369f9
    echo    'Loading Xen 4.1-amd64 ...'
    multiboot   /xen-4.1-amd64.gz placeholder
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-24-generic ...'
    module  /vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic placeholder root=UUID=30be364b-d53e-4222-af51-591e0a1b68ad ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    module  /initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
```

Error:

```
not enough memory to relocate the dom0 kernel image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://bugzilla.xensource.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1813) for that type of machine.